# How can I get my bindingSource to support sorting?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-5, bindingsource

I am trying to make a master-details form, with the master records bound to one binding source, and the details datagridview bound to a second binding source

It works pretty well, only the `childBindingSource.SupportSorting` property is false.
`masterBindingSource.SupportsSorting` is true.  Is there a way I can get the `childBindingSource` to support sorting - given that it is based on another binding source that does support sorting?

```
masterBindingSource.DataSource = GetBindingSource()   // .SupportsSorting = true
childBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource   // .SupportsSorting = false
childBinding.DataMember = ChildItems

private BindingSource GetBindingSource()
{
   DbSet<ContactEvent> dset = Db.ContactEvents;
   IOrderedQueryable<ContactEvent> qry = dset.Where(p => p.Id > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Id);
   qry.Load();

   BindingList<ContactEvent> bindinglist = dset.Local.ToBindingList();
   var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
   bindingSource.DataSource = bindinglist;
   return bindingSource;
}
```

Comment: This is Windows Forms, right?

Comment: Yes - oops, i meant to tag it as such - have done now.

Comment: I know as much that [`BindingSource.SupportsSorting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.supportssorting.aspx) is a read-only property: _true if the data source is an IBindingList and supports sorting; otherwise, false._ Further, setting DataMember resests the inner list of a binding source, apparently into a list not meeting these two conditions. But I fail to know what to do about it. Maybe you're lucky and a WinForms whiz like Hans Passant will bump into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help we got this working using
[this link at codeplex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c111d3f25f40#src/EntityFramework/Internal/SortableBindingList%60.cs)

I had to change my class to use the SortableBindingList instead of BindingList.
It was interesting to me that BindingList alone was good enough for a grid at the master level - but not for a grid containing details.